# QGIS 3.0 not able to load processing plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, mac, qgis-3

I solved issues in the past opening my vector menu options with my processing plugin (in version 2.16), but recently upgraded my computer to a Mac OS 10.13 and my QGIS to version 3.0.1. My vector menu once again wasn't showing, but when I went to **Plugins->Processing** I got an error that I didn't understand which is shown below.

Can anyone help me through this?

> Couldn't load plugin 'processing'
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'  Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 311, in loadPlugin
>       **import**(packageName)   File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 664, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File
>   "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/**init**.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       from processing.tools.dataobjects import *          # NOQA   File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 664, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File
>   "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/dataobjects.py",
>   line 51, in 
>       from processing.algs.gdal.GdalUtils import GdalUtils   File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 664, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File
>   "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/GdalUtils.py",
>   line 35, in 
>       from osgeo import gdal   File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py",
>   line 664, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
>
> Python version: 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 05:52:31) [GCC
>   4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]  QGIS version: 3.0.1-Girona Girona, exported

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.

Comment: I have the same problem, can anyone help!!